# Force case insensitive with OCI in PHP (oracle database)

Tags: php, oracle

Well, the title explains it well...

I'm using [OCI](http://php.net/manual/es/book.oci8.php) to explore a Oracle database in PHP.

The trouble is that the database is case sensitive, so... when I execute a sentence like

```
SELECT COUNT(username) count, username FROM transactions WHERE username IS NOT NULL GROUP BY username
```

returns an array like this

```
COUNT USERNAME
213   EMG_COTORA
31    EMG_cotora
123   emg_cotora
```

This because the database is case sensitive, so... How do I force case insensitive without modifying the database? (I haven't write permission)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that in your actual query you have a `GROUP BY` clause.  You would just need to group by the `UPPER(username)`

```
SELECT upper(username), count(*) cnt
  FROM transactions
 WHERE username IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY upper(username)
```

You could also, of course, `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` `lower(username)` or `initcap(username)` or any other function that converts the different username values into a single value.

Comment: Your assumption is right, and your answer perfect. I've modified the question in order to make it more explicit, Thanks you!

Comment: (As a note: indexing on `upper(username)` will speed up the query if you're performing it often)